# Disable download for a single dependency

Tags: java, maven-2, quartz-scheduler

I am downright annoyed because the Quartz release I'm importing does not have a proper POM file deployed ([maven repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/opensymphony/quartz/1.6.3/)).

Therefore maven dutifully tries to download it on *every build*.

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/opensymphony/quartz/1.6.3/quartz-1.6.3.pom
```

I'd like to skip this step but *without going completely offline* since that is useful.

Ideas?

Comment: Strange, the 1.6.1 release does contain the POM.  What's up with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an additional repository, with this artifact and make sure the POM is correct. This way the main repo POM will be overridden. You can run repository manager such as [artifactory](http://www.jfrog.org/products.php) or [nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) locally

Comment: This is a very good solution.  I've used it for things like JTOpen which is at version 6.0 in the central repository, but at 6.5.1 on SourceForge.  It seems annoying at first, but it's better than fighting with the central repos when a project team doesn't keep it up to date.

Answer (score 2):

If its a transitive dependency that isn't actually required, then you can use the [`<exclude />`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) element to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You could host the POM in a local repository manager, or in your local repository. If it's really bugging you I'd recommend contacting the project team and asking them to fix their metadata or raising a [request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEV) directly against the central repository with your own fix. Details on how to raise a request can be found [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-maven-evangelism.html)